# React Native - Is it possible to download multiple assets using rn-fetch-blob?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, camera-roll, rn-fetch-blob

Is there a way to download an array of objects (of .mp4, .jpg, etc...) using rn-fetch-blob? Right now this code is grabbing a single .mp4 url, but what if I have an array of .mp4 mixed in with some .jpg? How would I do such a thing?

say I have data:

```
const data = [
  {media: url.jpg}, 
  {media: url.mp4}, 
  {media: url.mp4}, 
  {media: url.jpg}
]
```

How do I setup my fetch so it will loop through data, and I can do something after CameraRoll?

```
RNFetchBlob.config({
  fileCache: true,
  appendExt: 'mp4',
}).fetch(
    'GET',
    'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
  )
  .then(res => {
    CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(res.path())
      .then(async () => {
        // works
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('err:', err));
  });
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

---

Edit: I haven't tested this, but just looking at what I wrote, is this going to be an issue?

```
for ( let foo of data ) {

  // write out some code to see if the url has .mp4 or .jpg extension?

  RNFetchBlob.config({
    fileCache: true,
    appendExt: 'mp4', // variable of the correct extension
  }).fetch(
      'GET',
      foo.media, // from the data object?
    )
    .then(res => {
      CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(res.path())
        .then(async () => {
          // works
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('err:', err));
    });
}
```

Or is there a much simpler way of doing this?

Comment: The underlying impl is [FIFO](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/blob/master/ios/RNFetchBlob/RNFetchBlob.m#L55), and requests are executed [in sequence](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/blob/master/ios/RNFetchBlobNetwork.m#L90). So your code is fine, I could not think of a better way unless underlying impl changes.

Comment: @SDEZero hello! sorry, can you explain like i'm 5? hehe sorry. still wrapping my head around all this. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. Are you asking if your loop can be parallelized, or you are asking if your code would be working(you don't care about parallelization)?

Comment: @SDEZero hello - I was asking if what I had is the best practice, or cleanest way to downloading multiple media files, if given a set of data objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this codes:

```
const data = [
  {media: url.jpg}, 
  {media: url.mp4}, 
  {media: url.mp4}, 
  {media: url.jpg}
]

data.map((item) => {

    const extention = item.media.split(".").pop(); // <-- get item extention

    RNFetchBlob.config({
        fileCache: true,
        appendExt: extention,  // <-- extention
    }).fetch(
        'GET',
        item.media, // <-- item url
    )
    .then(res => {
      CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(res.path())
      .then(async () => {
        // works
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('err:', err));
    });

})
```

Comment: This works for me. Do you think this is the cleanest/performant way?